# main Python process and interconnection with ProcessPoolExecutor

Tags: python, concurrent.futures

What kind of structure that a main Python process gets results from ProcessPoolExecutor after, on exemple, map command has been invoked.

Answer (score 1):

You can call on

> executor.map

function for getting the results. Here's a really good [example](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#processpoolexecutor-example) in python docs.

**EDITED (to answer the question)**

It uses a queue(from multiprocessing module) for scheduling calls and another for the results if any. Its like a consumer-producer model. I think that reading this [code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/concurrent/futures/process.py) will be very enlightenment. Its very well documented.

Comment: Sure, thanks. But what I meant. What structure, like queue or pipe, is being used to communicate between forked child processes and main process to get a result eventually.